# Automatically adjust volume based on time of day?

Tags: volume-control

I'd like to run a script based on the time of the day, that changes to volume output through the jack-port. Is the an existing script that could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, experiment with the `amixer` command. See `man amixer` for examples, like this:

```
amixer -c 1 -- sset Master playback -20dB
```

will  set  the  master  volume  of  the second card to -20dB.

Then, run the correct command as an hourly `cron` job to adjust the volume.